Package can not be resolved in Xcode

Package.resolved file is corrupted or malformed; fix or delete the file to continue: unknown 'PinsStorage' version '3' at '.../project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved'.

This happens after adding package https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift
We already did a clean build and deleted derived data but it is still not working.

Did you try to delete the Package.resolved file as well?

Xcode 15.3 brought the version 3 format. If you open a project with such a Package.resolve in Xcode 15.2 for example, this would cause issues

there might be some conflicts in the resolved file, try to see if there if resolved file is properly formatted.

Make sure you're using XCode >= 15.3 to solve the unknown 'PinsStorage' version '3' error

Did it for me. Was getting this issue on my CD/CI and just had to update my stack :)

I'm using Xcode 15.4 but getting this error still. Any suggestions?

@LukeIrvin are you getting this error on local on in CI? Make sure you're really using xcode >= 15.3.
Also, if you're really using 15.4 and it is not working, try to downgrade to 15.3 and check.

@bogdanRazvan on CI (Github Actions)

@LukeIrvin I would try to find out which package is causing this, and see if there's a new version to update to, potentially fixing this issue.

Try the following step as mentioned in the first screenshot.

Then add the dependency after following steps mentioned in second screenshot.

It should work properly now. I tried this and it worked fine for me.
